# access MainPage.xaml button in MainActivity

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is my first contact with Xamarin Forms, so maybe (and probably) I'm doing things in the wrong way.

I have the following Xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Orientation="Vertical"
                 Spacing="15" x:Name="stackLayout">

        <Button x:Name="giveFeedback" Text="Start Recording" Clicked="OnStartRecording" />
        <Button x:Name="stopRecording" Text="Stop Recording" IsEnabled="false" Clicked="OnStopRecording" />

        <Label Text="Feedback:" />
        <Editor x:Name="feedbackTranscription" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        </Editor>

        <Button x:Name="saveFeedback" IsEnabled="false"  Text="Save feedback" Clicked="OnSave" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I want to access the microphone of the device to capture audio. After a little research, I've found the MediaRecorder class for android. The problem is that I can't figure out how to access elements from MainPage.xaml on MainActivity class.

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        MediaRecorder _recorder;
        Button _start;
        Button _stop;

        string path = "/sdcard/test.3gpp";

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            //_start.Click += delegate {
            //    _stop.Enabled = !_stop.Enabled;
            //    _start.Enabled = !_start.Enabled;

            //    _recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
            //    _recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.ThreeGpp);
            //    _recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);
            //    _recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
            //    _recorder.Prepare();
            //    _recorder.Start();
            //};

            //_stop.Click += delegate {
            //    _stop.Enabled = !_stop.Enabled;

            //    _recorder.Stop();
            //    _recorder.Reset();
            //};

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

in the case I would like to bind giveFeedback and stopRecording to _start and _stop buttons of MainActivity class. I've examples with a `FindById<Button>(Resource.Id.start)`. Should I set id's for my buttons and do the same? Should I use MVVM?

PS: For now, I just want to learn Xamarin Forms with Android.

Comment: You should use DependencyService and call the method to start or stop recording in xaml.cs or in viewmodel if you use MVVM

Comment: can this record even gibberish words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create interface like this in PCL

```
    public interface PortableInterface
    {
        object GetLogicFromAndroidProject();
    }
```

Add Extend this interface in your android project like below

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PortableInterfaceRenderer))]
namespace YourProjectName.iOS
{

    public class PortableInterfaceRenderer : PortableInterface
    {
        public object GetLogicFromAndroidProject()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // here write your logic 
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have to call this method in PCL project

```
var obj = DependencyService.Get<PortableInterface>().GetLogicFromAndroidProject();
```

Hope this will help

Comment: do I need to register the dependency anywhere or it does automatically through reflection?

Comment: I have already added the code.  [assembly: Dependency(typeof(PortableInterfaceRenderer))] This is the registration code. Then it will be call automatically.

Comment: My bad, I`m used with Startup.cs or a bootstrap class for that. Thanks